# Should we address how to vote in the site tour?

Tags: feature-request, answers, site-definition, voting, tour

It seems that vote wars have been a problem in the past on this site.  I noticed the site tour does not cover how we should vote, and am recommending it be updated to include this information to help reduce the occurrence of vote wars, and to have voting better represent the answers here.  I propose adding the following (or a variation of it) as @AffableGeek posted in part of an answer to another [question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4462/1039):

> Ideally, when you are voting, you are saying "This answer is informative and reflective of the tradition for which it claims to speak." Downvotes mean "this misrepresents the tradition" not "I don't like it."

Comment: It was a problem in the past, but it doesn't seem to be a current problem. Or are you aware of it being a current problem?

Comment: I am not really sure if vote wars are still a bad problem, but believe to some degree it is a problem.  I believe it would help make the site better if voters in general knew to vote this way on answers.

Comment: I think the addition is congruent with current site culture. I favor this improvement.

Comment: Unfortunately sites don't get that much control over the tour page.

Comment: -1: `I am not really sure if vote wars are still a bad problem, but believe to some degree it is a problem.` Well I'm glad you're so  certain. ;)

Answer (score 7):

I think the addition is congruent with current site culture. I favor this improvement.

Comment: I posted as an answer so people could vote on it.

Comment: I'm biased, but I agree :) The problem isn't so much with the concept as the execution - I don't know that we actually get to modify the tour page

Comment: @AffableGeek I don't know either. We'll find out eventually.